# Streaming m3u8 Radio on Android 4.0 without Vitamio

Tags: android, streaming, m3u8

Why Aqua Player and VLC can stream m3u8 HLS radio stream on every version of Android? There isn't any github open source project to see what are they doing to stream this kind of radio?